# InstaBug, cannot resolve 'Builder'

Tags: android, instabug

Trying to implement InstaBug first time, however, when I initialize it,

```
 new Instabug.Builder(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .setInvocationEvent(Instabug.IBGInvocationEvent.IBGInvocationEventShake)
            .build();
```

Android Studio says cannot resolve symbol `Builder` 
Though Builder extends from *java.lang.Object* , helpless to figure why this happens. Any fix?

EDIT:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0"
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.1'
compile project(":volley")
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile ("com.instabug.library:instabugsupport:+") { exclude group: 'com.mcxiaoke.volley', module: 'library' }
```

Comment: Where is your build.gradle ?

Comment: I've edited the question!

Comment: [take a look](https://github.com/Instabug/android-sample)

Answer (score 1):

`Instabug.Builder` was introduced in v2+ of Instabug SDK.

Can you try specifying the latest version of Instabug in your gradle, as follows:

```
compile('com.instabug.library:instabugcompat:2.2.1')
```

P.S: `v2.2.1` was latest at the time of writing

P.S2: `instabugcompat` is the equivalent of `instabugsupport` in v2+

P.S3: Instabug doesn't include Volley anymore so you don't need to exclude it anymore

For more details, don't hesitate to ask. And you can check [this out](https://github.com/Instabug/android-sample) as well as @m-d mentioned